# Adding a value to next cell in datagridview on selection of combo box and deleting the selectedcombo value

Tags: c#

> The price column should be changed as soon as Combo box value selected

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    refresh();
}
public void refresh()
{
    CSqlOperations operation = new CSqlOperations();

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + 1;
    ArrayList columnProduct = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        columnProduct.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

    for (int i = 0; i < columnProduct.Count; i++)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = operation.getPrice(columnProduct[i].ToString()); 
}
```

**The current select value should be deleted from combo box and the price should populate in price column as combo value selected**

Comment: So what issue you are facing with this code? Did you debug the code?

Comment: @chetan when I select combo box value the price doesn't get changed immediately , it change on click .